# Time taken to sort array, when CPU operates on 10^8 operations/sec

Tags: arrays, sorting, time-complexity, mergesort, insertion-sort

**Assume that a CPU can process 10^8 operations per second. Suppose you have to sort an array with 10^6 elements. Which of the following is true?**

1. Insertion sort will always take more than 2.5 hours while merge sort will always take less than 1 second.
2. Insertion sort will always take more than 2.5 hours while quicksort will always take less than 1 second
3. Insertion sort could take more than 2.5 hours while merge sort will always take less than 1 second.
4. Insertion sort could take more than 2.5 hours while quicksort will always take less than 1 second.

Comment: Where did you fail trying to answer the question?

Comment: I didn't know how to approach in order to solve the problem @Rotem

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a homework machine.

Comment: if someone don't know about a programming related problem he can get help from the developers which i think more efficient than a teacher. just open your mind bro... And the answer of the question would help million of users like me...!! @bhspencer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worst case complexity of Insertion sort & Quick Sort is O(n^2).

Worst case complexity of merge sort is O(n*log(n))

therefore, for insertion sort & quick sort no. of steps are `(10^6)^2 = 10^12`

so it takes `10^12/10^8 = 10^4 or 10,000 seconds = 2.77hrs` (as CPU operates 10^8 steps/sec)

where as, no. of steps for merge sort is `(10^6*log(10^6)) = 6*10^6` steps which takes `(6*10^6/10^8) = 0.06secs` which is less than 1

but as the case may be option 1 or 3 could be correct, here the insertion sort can take less than 2.5hrs depending on the problem, cause average-case complexity for insertion sort is `(N-1)*N/4` calculating running time for it, we got `0.69hrs` which is lesser than 2.5hrs so the 3rd statement is correct.

Answer (score 0):

What's the worst-case complexity of insertion sort?

What's the worst-case complexity of mergesort and quicksort?

Is it possible that insertion sort lasts less than 2.5 hours? If it is, what's the case?

What's the best-case complexity of quicksort (or mergesort)?
What's the best-case complexity of insertion sort?

If you answer these questions. You'll easily answer yours.

If you don't know what worst-case or best-case means, then try to find answers to these questions.

If sorting takes 10^12 steps, how long does it last in seconds (or hours) if your CPU does 10^8 steps per second?
How many steps does it take to sort an array of length `n` for quicksort, mergesort or insertion sort?

Answering all of the questions above leads you one step closer to answering your question.
Do it, and I guarantee you, you'll be able to answer it immediately.

Comment: Worst case complexity of insertion sort is O(n^2)

Comment: Worst case complexity of insertion sort is O(n^2)
Worst case complexity of merge sort is O(n*log(n))
Worst case complexity of quick sort is O(n^2)

therefore, for insertion sort & qick sort no. of steps are 10^12
so it takes 10^4 or 10 thousand seconds = 2.77hrs
where as, no. of steps for merge sort is 6*10^6 steps
which takes (6*10^6/10^8)=0.06secs which is less than 1.

have i done correct @Looft ?????

Comment: @SubhankarPaul Yep, this is right. Although, best-case complexity of insertion sort is O(n) which means insertion sort could last longer than 2.5 hours, average-case complexity isn't needed to answer the question.